# Crystalreports show report with scroll bar

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have a C# application where I need to load report using *Crystal Reports*. By default, *Crystal Report* loads first page only. We need to click on *"next"* button to view next page. We wanted to load report with a *scrollbar* without using next button to jump to next page. I found following solution online:

```
SeparatePages = "false";
```

I applied this solution to my report but now it has stopped showing page header and page footer to all internal pages. Is there a way I can load report using a scroll bar and I should be able to show page header and page footer in all internal pages too?

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid can't provide you the required solution but can adivce you a wrokaround.

1. For all sections check option "Underlay following sections"